# How to mount external usb hard drive Slackware

Tags: mount, external-hdd, slackware

I can detect drives like this:

```
cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0 2930266584 sda
   8        1     512000 sda1
   8        2  372669440 sda2
   8        3  409600000 sda3
   8        4 1364700160 sda4
   8       16 1953514584 sdb
   8       17          1 sdb1
   8       21 1953506520 sdb5
```

It is `sdb`

But problem is when I try to list it with `fdisk` it not working
here is the result:

```
bash-4.2# fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf82d9516

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048   746364927   372669440    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      3475765248  4294965247   409600000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       746364928  3475765247  1364700160   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Same happend with `gdisk`

Anyone know what is problem?

**ADITIONL DETAILS:**
It works ok on Windows 7.
lsusb return HD it is last one 'Samsung Electronics Co.'....

```
bash-4.2# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1c4f:0003 SiGma Micro HID controller
Bus 002 Device 049: ID 04e8:6031 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
```

`dmesg` returns:

```
[184764.877200] sd 32:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[184764.877397] usb 2-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 48
[184764.882609] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[184764.882613] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[184764.882616] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[184764.882618] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[184764.882619] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
[184764.882627] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[184764.882630] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[184764.882636] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 1
[184764.882640] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 2
[184764.882643] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 3
[184764.882816] REISERFS warning (device sdb1): sh-2006 read_super_block: bread failed (dev sdb1, block 8, size 1024)
[184764.882819] REISERFS warning (device sdb1): sh-2006 read_super_block: bread failed (dev sdb1, block 64, size 1024)
[184764.882821] REISERFS warning (device sdb1): sh-2021 reiserfs_fill_super: can not find reiserfs on sdb1
[184764.882984] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[184764.883006] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[184764.883008] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[184878.468123] usb 2-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 49 using ehci-pci
[184878.554285] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6031
[184878.554289] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[184878.554291] usb 2-1.6: Product: m3 portable 3.0
[184878.554292] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[184878.554294] usb 2-1.6: SerialNumber: 303030303030303030303030
[184878.554578] usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[184878.554714] scsi33 : usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0
[184879.558489] scsi 33:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SAMSUNG  m3 portable 3.0  0205 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[184879.562427] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[184880.851100] .ready
[184880.851886] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[184880.852688] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[184880.852692] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 1f 00 10 08
[184880.853449] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[184880.883735]  sdb: sdb1 < sdb5 >
[184880.883858] sdb: p5 size 3907050168 extends beyond EOD, enabling native capacity
[184880.887024]  sdb: sdb1 < sdb5 >
[184880.887117] sdb: p5 size 3907050168 extends beyond EOD, truncated
[184880.889637] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[184911.117227] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 49 using ehci-pci
```

`cat /proc/partitions`

```
bash-4.2# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0 2930266584 sda
   8        1     512000 sda1
   8        2  372669440 sda2
   8        3  409600000 sda3
   8        4 1364700160 sda4
   8       16 1953514584 sdb
   8       17          1 sdb1
   8       21 1953506520 sdb5
```

Comment: First of all, are you sure that you have a working usb disk? Do you get any input from "lsusb"? Also try to run "dmesg" after you plug in your device and see any relevant messages. The /proc/partitions file reveals something weird regarding this disk. Have you tried the disk on another machine btw? Is it working? Does it have more than one partitions (the usb disk)? Last but not least, if it's a NTFS filesystem, download ntfs-3g and try to fix any dirty or bad clusters on the disk with "sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sdbX"

Comment: Please check updated main question....

Comment: ok.. Did you also try the ntfsfix command? It won't destroy any of your data.. Sometimes when you are using a disk on Windows & Linux too, if you forcefully shutdown Windows machine that had the relevant usb disk connected to it, it may leave some "dirty" stuff in the disk and then you are having problems with mounting the disk on your Linux system. Also with mount command (running with sudo), can you mount the device?

Comment: I get this for `ntfsfix` `Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.` How can I format disk from linux terminal?

Comment: Check these examples: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/fsck-command-examples

Comment: I foramted HD with ex4 from windows and then tried to mount on Slackware but same... fdisk, gdisk still cannot recognize device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52009/discussion-between-blametheadmin-and-vladimir).